# Finding a MacLaurin polynomial

Tags: calculus

[image]

**A.** So for this problem, I used the $sin(x)$ expansion formula to properly right out the polynomial for $sin(6t^2)$. The top answer given is the simplified formula for that problem. However, it's telling me that the variable t cannot be written in the answer, which confuses me. Isn't the polynomial supposed to be $6t^2$ for all x in the expansion formula?

**B.** For the second one, I'm not sure how to go about taking the integral of the problem, given that we cannot go beyond degree 7 (because of the polynomial), so that leaves me stranded.

Any kind of guidance on how to approach these two problems would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Maclaurin polynomial for $\sin(6t^2)$ has first two terms equal to
$$6t^2-\frac{(6t^2)^3}{3!}, \quad\text{that is,} \quad 6t^2-36t^6.$$
Integrate term by term from $0$ to $x$.

We get $2x^3 -\frac{36}{7}x^7$.

Comment: So is the polynomial I entered in the first box correct, and I just need to go through and integrate each term?

Comment: The first two terms are correct *for the expansion* of $\sin(6t^2)$. The next term is not but we don't need it. However, you needed to integrate from $0$ to $x$. What needed to be in the box is $2x^3-\frac{36}{7}x^7$.

Comment: @etree. You are asked for $F(x)$ which is the result of the integration over $t$ using bounds $0$ and $x$. So, $t$ must not appear in the formula. Concerning the mistakes for the numbers, André Nicolas already commented.